# How to get the size of the new swift AttributedString?

Tags: swift, size, nsattributedstring, attributedstring

NSAttributedString has a `size()` method which the new AttributedString lacks. How do you get the size of the new AttributedString?

Comment: Well it depends, what *exactly* do you mean by size?

Comment: I have the same doubt as @Alexander , by 'size' do you mean the font size or the character count of your string?

Comment: From the documentation of NSAttributedString.size(): `Returns the size necessary to draw the string.`

Answer (score 2):

You could convert your AttributedString to an [NSAttributedString](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsattributedstring/3787788-init) and then call the `size` method, although this seems more like a workaround.

```
let myNSAttributedString = NSAttributedString(myAttributedString)
myNSAttributedString.size()
```

Comment: Any non-workarounds?